# The Snake in the 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, multidimensional-array

I have to write a program that creates a two dimensional array and fills it like a snake. Here is the task itself:

> Blockquote write a program that creates a two-dimensional numeric array and this array is filled with a "snake": first the first row (from left to right), then the last column (from top to bottom), the last row (from right to left), the first column (from bottom to top), the second row ( left to right), etc.

I tried to write something, but bugs constantly appear. Please help to shorten this code and make it correct.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int len = rand.Next(5, 20);
        int wid = rand.Next(5, 20);
        int[,] arr = new int[len, wid];
        int num = 10;
        int line = 0;
        int line2 = len;
        int col = wid - 1;
        int col2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= (len > wid ? len : wid); i++)
        { 
            for (int k = 0; k < wid; k++, num++)
            {
                arr[line, k] = num;
            }
            line++;

            for (int k = 0; k < len; k++, num++)
            {
                arr[k, col] = num;
            }
            col++;

            for (int k = (wid - 1); k >= 0; k--, num++)
            {
                arr[line2, k] = num;
            }
            line2++;

            for (int k = 0; k < (len - 1); k++, num++)
            {
                arr[k, col2] = num;
            }
            col2++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
            for (int q = 0; q <= wid; q++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i, q] + "   ");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not really how we ask questions here. Making code better doesn't help anyone in the future to any great extent. However, we do deal with specific problems and try to give concrete solutions. Maybe its at this point you take a read of [ask]

Comment: Your code is full of errors, you iterate over variables but don't check array dimension

Comment: "This is not really how we ask questions here. Making code better doesn't help anyone in the future to any great extent. However, we do deal with specific problems and try to give concrete solutions. Maybe its at this point you take a read of How to Ask – The General". thanks, I'll keep it in mind in the future! I'm a newbie so didn't know the rules. I apologize

Comment: @user:3486763 thank you, Stanislav! Then I will try to figure it out myself, but I will not close the question in case someone gives a specific answer on how to change the code!)